# linkedin api "Not Enough permissions to access: PartnerApiSocialAction.GET.202311" error

Tags: linkedin-api

i am fetching the comments with an authorized member have the right permissions to interact with the linkedin developer api's. other api's are working fine but for the socialActions api's giving the error.
`{ status:403, serviceErrorCode:100, code:'ACCESS_DENIED', message:'Not enough permissions to access: partnerApiSocialAction.GET.20231101' }`

i have also check the permissions from the linkedin documentation, all required permissions i have.
here is the provided link for the docs
[text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/community-management/shares/network-update-social-actions?view=li-lms-2023-11&tabs=http)

base url is: https://api.linkedin.com/rest
interacted url: [https://api.linkedin.com/rest/socialActions/{shareUrn|ugcPostUrn|commentUrn}/comments/{commentId}](https://api.linkedin.com/rest/socialActions/%7BshareUrn%7CugcPostUrn%7CcommentUrn%7D/comments/%7BcommentId%7D)

what things needs to add for this api to get or for the reading the comments from the authorized memeber?

I have been tried to add with different scopes and permissions but the socialActions couldn't find.
if you face this issue, let us know.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this question is I was using the base URL
baseURL: https://api.linkedin.com/rest

Need to update the baseURL to   https://api.linkedin.com/v2

and it will resolve your issues.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You should avoid the `v2` path. That is a legacy version of the API, and it will be phased out. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/versioning?view=li-lms-2023-11#whats-changing

Comment: Although I note that LinkedIn still lists it for some of their API documentation, e.g. member profiles at /v2/me, have asked them if these are remaining or not because the site keeps telling you that /v2 are sunset and no longer available [but they still work, and are documented as the default way to get profile data!].

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying out different permissions to see what will work, you need to make sure that you **wait at least 5 minutes between each test**, because there is [a nasty caching bug in the LinkedIn API auth implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77847103/linkedin-api-access-denied-not-enough-permissions-to-access).

If you create a new access token within 5 minutes of your previous API call, then your new access token might use the permissions of the old access token (for 5 minutes). It's pretty infuriating.

I [created a demo app](https://github.com/twobitfool/linkedin-auth-bug/) to prove this bug when I reported the issue to LinkedIn a while back. I'm guessing it will never get fixed, based on the most recent message from LinkedIn Developer Support...

> Developers usually don't have this pattern of trying to generate token for different combination of permissions. This is more like rare use case.
> For now we have added this feedback to our roadmap. Unfortunately, we don't have concrete timeline as to when this will be implemented into production.