# The LinkedIn Comments API doesn't work in the latest version

Tags: linkedin-api

When using the versioned API to post a comment on a post, it returns a 403 error

```
{
  "status": 403,
  "serviceErrorCode": 100,
  "code": "ACCESS_DENIED",
  "message": "Not enough permissions to access: partnerApiSocialActions.CREATE.20231101"
}
```

However, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77746522/3416313) if I use the "legacy" unversioned API `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/` for the same endpoint, it works even though the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/versioning?view=li-lms-2023-11#whats-changing) say that it is available only until June 30, 2023. Why is this happening?

Comment: Have you tried generating a new "Primary Client Secret"?

Comment: @MicheleDeFalco no. How is it supposed to help? And what do you mean by "primary"? There is only one Client secret, no?

Comment: yes that's what I meant, in the linkedin apps dashboard, it calls it "primary client secret, https://www.linkedin.com/developers/apps

Comment: I have tested it on 2 different apps and it happens in both of them so I guess updating the client secret won't help really. Also, how can you even update it?

Comment: Enter the link I posted to access the list of your LinkedIn apps, and from the "Auth" tab in the "Application Credentials" section you have the option to update the "Client Secret", you can only do this if it has expired.

Comment: then activate the products you need in the "Products" tab.

Comment: I tried. But still getting the same error.